# Need help understanding the proof of the gaussian integral

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am working with the Gaussian integral at the moment, and all the proofs I have seen involve a step where it is said that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}re^{-r^2}drdϕ$. I can see why that $might$ be the case, but I don't really understand it. Could anyone explain how exactly one arrives at this result?

Comment: This is just integration by [change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) to polar coordinates.

Comment: I know that but what I don't understand is how one does the switch to polar coordinates

Answer (score 1):

Set
\begin{align}
  & x=r \cos \theta  \\ 
 & y=r \sin \theta  \\ 
\end{align}
Then
$$x^2+y^2=r^2$$
and
$$dxdy=\left| \frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (r ,\theta )} \right|dr\,d\theta={{r}\, dr\,d\theta  }$$